# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClickForgot(View) in a parent or ancestor

Tags: java, android, xml

I am getting an error in forgot password activity, while clicking on forgot password the app is stopping and getting an error as

> Process: com.example.beasport.sport, PID: 5878
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClickForgot(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'forgotpassword'
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

My forgot password activity and corresponding `xml` file are:

**ResetForgotActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class ResetPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail;

private Button btnReset, btnBack;

private FirebaseAuth auth;

private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.forgotpassword);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Enter your registered email id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)

                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}

}
```

**forgotpassword.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Login">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_forgot_password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password_msg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/btn_reset_password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_back"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Why am I getting this error? It would be helpful if anyone could help me to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you likely need to rebuild your project. It looks like you previously set the click listeners in the XML, and the changes have not been pushed to the device. Also disable instant run if it is enabled

Comment: I've rebuild the project several times but it is causing the same error and my application keeps stopping @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: There is no `View` in that layout with ID `forgotpassword`. You're likely looking at the wrong `Activity` and layout. The stack trace is saying that you have a `TextView` with ID `forgotpassword`, and an `onClick` attribute with value `"onClickForgot"`, and the appropriate method for that value can't be found in the `Activity` that loads that layout.

Comment: Then what should I do? @MikeM.

Comment: Look in the `Activity` that's crashing when you click. The one that has a layout with a `TextView` with ID `forgotpassword`, and an `onClick` attribute with value `"onClickForgot"`.